# Unable to locate file through winscp

Tags: putty, winscp

I logined as root to one machine through winscp and create a directory at some location "**/home/user/testdata/**" but When i logined to same machine through putty and try to locate that location using locate command, I am unable to locate and also i can locate some files through putty but when i login through winscp, I am unable to find those file, I tried refresh and relogin.

Comment: When logged in through Putty, can you see the files in /home/root/?

Comment: no ,same is the case for /home/root/

Comment: try `ls -ltr /home/user/testdata/` to check if your files are listed or may be simply you do not have enough permission to read it. did you use the same user for both winscp and putty?